# Optimization problem involving Gradient Descent where learning rate is also varying in gradient descent manner

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative, gradient-descent

**Problem statement**

$i(t) = \frac{1}{b_0}(y(t)^{(4)} + a_3y(t)^{(3)} + a_2y(t)^{(2)} + a_1y(t)^{(1)} -i(t)^{(1)})$

$i(t) = w_1(t)u_1(t) + w_2(t)u_2(t)$

$e(t)  = 0.5\times(r(t)-y(t))^2$

$w_n(t+1) = w_n(t)-\eta \frac{\partial{e}}{\partial{w}}, n=1,2$

$\eta(t+1) = \eta(t)-\alpha \frac{\partial{e}}{\partial{\eta}}$

Five equations are given above. I need to solve them to obtain the variations of weight $w(t)$ in terms of $b_i$'s and $a_i$'s,(which can be considered to be constants or system constants) and derivatives of $y(t).$ The numbers in the top of bracket in equation one symbolise different derivatives

**What I did**

If there were only first 4 equations and $\eta$ is a constant, then the above system is simple to solve by manipulation of partial derivatives as 
$\frac{\partial{e}}{\partial{w}} = \frac{\partial{e}}{\partial{y}}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{i}}\frac{\partial{i}}{\partial{w}}$ and then using first 3 equations to solve it.That part I was able to do easily.

But the problem here is that $\eta$ is also varying in the manner of gradient descent. How should I solve it now? Please give some hints so that I can reach to the solution

**Notations**
$y(t)$ is the output of the system, $i(t)$ is the input to the system, $r(t)$ is the reference input, $e(t)$ is the error, $w_1$ and $w_2$ are the weights, $\alpha$ is a constant, but \eta is varying as can be seen in equation 5. Equation 4 and 5 are gradient descent equations

Comment: Hi, you have $i(t)$ twice, it might also help if you list what each of these are.  Assuming you want to calculate $\partial{e}/\partial{\eta}$, you don't use $\eta$ in $e(t)$ and I can't see what $r(t)$ and $y(t)$ are.

Comment: $e(t)$ is the error between reference and output, whereas $\eta$ is a learning factor, which is itself varying. You can consider it as a kind of adaptive gradient descent, wherein the usual learning constant term is also varying